# watch arbitrary ng-repeat collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling trying to find the correct Angular Way to watch an arbitrary ng-repeat collection.
The goal is simply to receive the new list contents when content of ng-repeat changes. (Of course without knowing the collection name).

Say i add a `collection-update` directive like this:

```
<ul collection-update="updateCounter($list)">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items|uppercase">{{ item.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to receive the current ng-repeat items (filtered) on every list change.

I could rely on a announcer/notifier pattern, like http://plnkr.co/edit/6IrvzD9PcbskWq3C0qPr?p=preview but there's maybe something simpler, that could simply "watch" the collection.

Finally, the goal is to add 'indicators' support to http://blog.revolunet.com/angular-carousel.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `$watch`, see [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for more information.

From the docs:

> $watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)
>
> Registers a listener callback to be executed whenever the watchExpression changes.

As an example, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
scope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    updateCounter(newValue);
});
```

Comment: as said in the question, i want to watch the expression without knowing it (dynamically) and moreover, with any filters applied. (of course i'm aware of $watch)

Comment: If you want a separate part of your app to be notified, without explicitly coupling, you can use `$watch` and then `$broadcast`. You're obviously going to be aware of the `ng-repeat` expression where it is declared (i.e. a custom directive?), so you can set up a broadcast there - i.e. along the lines of a  `carouselChanged` event.

Comment: would be nice if the user just had to set "carousel" on its ul. then the directive itself take care of watching the ng-repeat expression.

Comment: Yeah - agreed, it would keep the templates nice and clean if it could all be wrapped up in a single line directive call.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, i found a way to solve this.

The trick is to literraly parse the ngRepeat expression in the link function and then simply watch it. I borrowed the code from the awesome [Ben Nadel AngularJS blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2457-Accessing-scope-On-The-DOM-Using-AngularJS.htm) and the result is visible here : http://plnkr.co/edit/qFVrxTCQ0OW1oMKeV647?p=preview

Tell me if you know any alternatives (builtin expression parsing for example)